# When is Jacobian invertible?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $(f,U)$ be a chart on $M$ a smooth $n$-manifold. I know the inverse function theorem by which $f$ is invertible on $U$ iff its Jacobian is. What about the other direction? Is there any theorem about conditions under which the Jabobian of a map $f$ is going to be invertible?

Comment: If both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are  differentiable, then the Jacobian of  $f$ is invertible.

Comment: @Landscape Thank you, do you have any reference?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't have any reference at hand, but you may prove it easily by differentiating $f^{-1}\circ f=\mathrm{id}$ with chain rule.

Comment: @Landscape Right, thanks! Unfortunately, it seems that it is not part of the definition of a chart that its inverse is also differentiable/smooth, or is it?

Comment: In the definition of a smooth manifold, the smoothness is reflected in the change of variables between intersecting charts.  Such a change of variables is always smooth with smooth inverse, so there is nothing to worry.

Comment: @Landscape Thank you. I will have to think about this for some time, it's not obvious to me.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Landscape already gave an answer:

> If both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable, then the Jacobian of $f$ is invertible. – Landscape Aug 2 at 13:41

I'll add a pointer to a more specialized result: for *harmonic* maps between open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, being invertible implies that the Jacobian is invertible at every point. This is a theorem of H. Lewy (1936). Unfortunately it fails in higher dimensions.